# SDLC models example?

Tags: sdlc

What the different types of SDLC models and in which systems are they most suitable for?

Comment: [SLDC](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SLDC) huh?

Comment: Software Development Life Cycle

Comment: In that case you have a typo in your first sentence: "I need to choose an SLDC..."

Comment: Do you also have it black-on-white that the specifications are cast in stone and won't change for as long as this system is in use? If not, you might want to look for something a bit more cyclic, so the process is prepared for the inevitable change requests that will come.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau don't forget that a rigid plan also makes it difficult to benefit from lessons learned as you develop. Change isn't only an external force.

Comment: @candied_orange, no argument there.

Answer (score 1):

The Waterfall Model is not a good choice. It was invented in 1970 by Winston Royce purely as an example for a process *that doesn't work*. And it is pretty good at what it was designed to do: not working.

Comment: Hmm, Wikipedia doesn't seem to agree, ["I believe the illustrated approach to be fundamentally sound."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_W._Royce). Also questions who invented it.

Comment: @user10600161, what do you mean with that it is a complex project? A project usually becomes complex due to uncertainty and that is where incremental (often agile) methods have their added value.

Comment: @candied_orange: The whole paper is a cautionary tale of disastrous information design. That quote, while it appears directly under figure #2 which is Waterfall, actually talks about figure #4, which is an incremental and iterative extension to Waterfall. The article is laid out in such a way that figure #2 (the non-working version) appears directly above the text talking about figure #4 (the working version), whereas figure #4 is on the next page. Also note that by "fundamentally sound", he doesn't mean "sound as the foundation of a software development process" but more like "sound as the …

Comment: … foundation for this paper in which we develop a software development process". He lists quite a number of problems with this first, improved version and then goes on to develop a host of further improvements, ending up with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICNhl.png Of course, the figure from the beginning looks much more appealing, so everybody just uses that, even though it doesn't work.